# Iterate a set of objects and store it to a list

Tags: java

Can some one help..

How to iterate this **set** and store it into a **list**.  I am getting null.

```
public class CartView {

    public void getCartProductsDetail(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                      HttpServletResponse response){
        List<Product> productsList=null;
        try {
            Map<Long,Integer> cart=SessionManager.getSession(request);
            Set<Long> products=cart.keySet();
            for(long productId: products){
                productsList.add(ProductDAO.getProductDetails(productId));
            }
            request.setAttribute("productsList", productsList);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
                .getRequestDispatcher(NavigationFiles.VIEW_CART);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

> How to iterate this set and store it into a list. I am getting null.

You forgot to initialize your variable `productsList`, it is still `null` when you call the `add` method that is why you get an error, as you can see below:

```
List<Product> productsList=null;
```

As you use Java 8 you can rely on the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to do this:

```
List<Product> productsList = cart.keySet()
    .stream()
    .map(ProductDAO::getProductDetails)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or simply initialize your variable with an `ArrayList` for example like this:

```
// Initialize the size of the array list with the size of products
// as it will be its final size which is faster than using the default
// constructor
productsList = new ArrayList<>(products.size());
```

**Response Update:**

As your method `ProductDAO.getProductDetails(long)` throws a `checked exception`, the current code based on the `Stream API` doesn't work since the map method doesn't support `Function` that throws `checked exceptions`.

You have 2 ways to fix it:

---

Create another method that will wrap the `checked exceptions` into an `unchecked exception` and throw this new exception, then you will be able to use this new method as function provided to the `map` method.

Something like that:

```
public static Product getProductDetailsSilently(long val) {
    try {
        return ProductDAO.getProductDetails(val);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

The code allowing to create the `List` of `Product` will then be:

```
List<Product> productsList = cart.keySet()
    .stream()
    .map(ProductDAO::getProductDetailsSilently)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Or rely on a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to do the same thing but in your `map` method as next:

```
List<Product> productsList = cart.keySet()
    .stream()
    .map(val -> {
        try {
            return ProductDAO.getProductDetails(val);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } 
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks..Its working now.  But stream is not working.

Comment: getting error on this line.      ProductDAO::getProductDetails   Error: surround try and catch block. I already surrounded with try and catch.

Comment: ok I see it is because getProductDetails throws an Exception, let me modify my answer then